# JS Fiddle. Saved code but not working like JSFiddle example

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsfiddle

I have found a very nice example on JSFiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/zra6fvtt/2/

When I try to save that, it does not work in my file which I created with the JSFiddle information. Here is my code:

```js
/* =========================================================
 * imageimageviewer.js
 * =========================================================
 * Controls the interaction with the product images on the PDP and collection PDP. A large image is presented with a
 * series of thumbnails. If there are more than X (configurable) thumbnails, a scroller allows the user to see the
 * others. Clicking on a thumbnail will change the large image. If the user scolls past the active thumbnail, the first thumbnail in the visible set will become active and the main image will update. If the user navigates by swiping the large image, the thumbnail strip will update to reflect the user's selection. 
 * ========================================================= */

(function(global, $, namespace) {

  "use strict";

  var Imageviewer = function Imageviewer(element, options) {
      this.init('imageviewer', element, options);
    },
    loggingDebug = true;

  //PUBLIC
  Imageviewer.prototype = {
    constructor: Imageviewer,
    init: function init(type, element, options) {
      if (loggingDebug) {
        console.debug('init imageviewer with options:');
        console.debug(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
      }

      var self = this;

      this.options = $.extend({}, $.fn[type].defaults, options);
      this.$element = $(element);
      this.$navigation = this.$element.find(this.options.thumbnail_container_class);
      this.$mainView = this.$element.find(this.options.large_container_class);
      this.totalSlides = this.$navigation.find(this.options.thumbnail_class).length;
      this.slidesToShow = self.options.slider_min;

      this.$navigation.find(this.options.thumbnail_class).first().addClass('active');

      this.$mainView.slick({
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        arrows: false,
        fade: true,
        infinite: false,
        onAfterChange: function() {
          var index = self.$mainView.slickCurrentSlide();
          // catch when user has dragged the main image and update the nav to match
          if (self.getActiveSlide() != index) {
            self.setActiveSlide(index);
            if (!self.isSlideVisible(index, self.$navigation.slickCurrentSlide())) {
              self.$navigation.slickGoTo(Math.floor(index / self.slidesToShow) * self.slidesToShow);
            }
          }
        }
      });

      this.$navigation.slick({
        slidesToShow: self.options.slider_min,
        slidesToScroll: self.options.slider_min,
        dots: false,
        infinite: false,
        onAfterChange: function() {
          var index = self.$mainView.slickCurrentSlide();
          if (!self.isSlideVisible(index, self.$navigation.slickCurrentSlide())) {
            self.$mainView.slickGoTo(self.getFirstVisibleSlide(self.$navigation.slickCurrentSlide()));
            self.setActiveSlide(self.getFirstVisibleSlide(self.$navigation.slickCurrentSlide()));
          }
        }
      });

      this.$navigation.find(this.options.thumbnail_class).click(function(e) {
        var index = parseInt(this.getAttribute('index'));
        self.setActiveSlide(index);
        self.$mainView.slickGoTo(index);
      });
    },
    getFirstVisibleSlide: function(currentSlide) {
      var firstSlide = currentSlide;
      if (currentSlide + this.slidesToShow >= this.totalSlides) {
        firstSlide = this.totalSlides - this.slidesToShow;
      }
      return firstSlide;
    },
    isSlideVisible: function(slideIndex, currentSlide) {
      var isVisible = false;
      if (currentSlide + this.slidesToShow > this.totalSlides) {
        isVisible = (slideIndex >= this.totalSlides - this.slidesToShow) && (slideIndex <= this.totalSlides - 1);
      } else {
        isVisible = (slideIndex >= currentSlide) && (slideIndex <= currentSlide + this.slidesToShow - 1);
      }
      return isVisible;
    },
    getActiveSlide: function() {
      var slideIndex = this.$navigation.find('.active').index() || 0;
      return slideIndex;
    },
    setActiveSlide: function(index) {
      this.$navigation.find(this.options.thumbnail_class).removeClass('active').end()
        .find("[index='" + index + "']").addClass('active')
    }

  };

  $.fn.imageviewer = function imageviewer(option) {
    var el = this,
      options = $.extend({}, $.fn.imageviewer.defaults, typeof option === 'object' && option);
    return el.each(function() {
      var data = $.data(this, 'imageviewer');
      if (!data) {
        $.data(this, 'imageviewer', (data = new Imageviewer(this, options)));
      } else {
        if (typeof option === 'object') {
          $.extend(data.options, option);
        }
      }
    });
  };

  $.fn.imageviewer.defaults = {
    large_container_class: ".viewer-main",
    thumbnail_container_class: ".viewer-thumbnails",
    thumbnail_class: ".viewer-thumb",
    slider_min: 5
  };

  $.fn.imageviewer.Constructor = Imageviewer;


  $(function() {
    $('[data-imageviewer]').imageviewer();
  });


}(this, window.jQuery, "CLIENT"));
```

```css
.viewer-thumbnails-container {
  margin: 0 40px;
}

.viewer-thumb {
  border: solid 2px transparent;
  margin: 2px;
}

.viewer-thumb.active {
  border: solid 2px black;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.slick-prev:before,
.slick-next:before {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.15/slick.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.15/slick.css">
<div class="product-image-viewer" data-imageviewer>
  <div class="viewer-main">
    <div>
      <img class="viewer-main-image" src="http://placehold.it/576x390&text=image+1" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img class="viewer-main-image" src="http://placehold.it/576x390&text=image+2" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img class="viewer-main-image" src="http://placehold.it/576x390&text=image+3" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img class="viewer-main-image" src="http://placehold.it/576x390&text=image+4" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img class="viewer-main-image" src="http://placehold.it/576x390&text=image+5" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img class="viewer-main-image" src="http://placehold.it/576x390&text=image+6" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img class="viewer-main-image" src="http://placehold.it/576x390&text=image+7" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img class="viewer-main-image" src="http://placehold.it/576x390&text=image+8" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="viewer-thumbnails-container">
    <div class="viewer-thumbnails">
      <div class="viewer-thumb">
        <img class="viewer-thumb-image" src="http://placehold.it/96x65&text=image+1" />
      </div>
      <div class="viewer-thumb">
        <img class="viewer-thumb-image" src="http://placehold.it/96x65&text=image+2" />
      </div>
      <div class="viewer-thumb">
        <img class="viewer-thumb-image" src="http://placehold.it/96x65&text=image+3" />
      </div>
      <div class="viewer-thumb">
        <img class="viewer-thumb-image" src="http://placehold.it/96x65&text=image+4" />
      </div>
      <div class="viewer-thumb">
        <img class="viewer-thumb-image" src="http://placehold.it/96x65&text=image+5" />
      </div>
      <div class="viewer-thumb">
        <img class="viewer-thumb-image" src="http://placehold.it/96x65&text=image+6" />
      </div>
      <div class="viewer-thumb">
        <img class="viewer-thumb-image" src="http://placehold.it/96x65&text=image+7" />
      </div>
      <div class="viewer-thumb">
        <img class="viewer-thumb-image" src="http://placehold.it/96x65&text=image+8" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have to import the base jQuery library too.

Comment: What errors do you get in the browser's console?

Comment: @pointy In External Resources, There is no Jquery Library given. But 1 Slik.min.js file and 1 slik.css files only. I embedded those. 
Can you please guide me how to add jquery

Comment: The fiddle tool provides a different way of importing a number of commonly used libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this tag `<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

jQuery is imported in the fiddle